# Cancelling blur handler based on item that was clicked

Tags: jquery, onclick, onblur

Hi again you wonderful people!

My issue this time is testing if a mouseClick has occurred with a blur statement.

I have a global solution where every input field is validated on BLUR.
Inside this event, I need to test if a certain element has been clicked (i.e. the helpBubble), if it has, I don't want the validation to occur, however, if that specific element has not been clicked, the validation still needs to happen.

Any help would be overwhelmingly appreciated!!

Answer (score 6):

The `blur` event of the previously-focused element will fire before the `click` event on the newly-focused element. As such, you cannot prevent validation onblur based on what you are moving to unless you add a timeout. For example:

```
var validationTimer;
$('#myform input').blur(function(){
  var blurred = $(this);
  validationTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    validationTimer = null;
    // Perform Validation on 'blurred'.
  },100);
});

$('.helpbubble').click(function(){
  if (validationTimer){
    clearTimeout(validationTimer);
    validationTimer = null;
  }
});
```

This will wait 100ms after the blur before performing validation, but if a click happens within that timeframe (it will happen almost immediately) it will be cancelled before it occurs.

**Edit**: Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9SzDP/

Comment: Thanks dude, I'll go investigate

Comment: Sorry to comment on a 2-year-old thread, but is your assertion that the blur event will always fire before the click event definitely true in all browsers?  Is that part of the spec?  I feel like assuming this may cause me cross-browser woes down the line.

Comment: @MikeTurley I believe it must work this way in all browsers, but I cannot cite a specification to back that up. Would you settle for running a simple test in all modern browsers and confirming the current behavior?

Comment: I will probably run this test, but even if it passes in all modern browsers I'm wary of implementing code based on this assumption, for fear that future browser updates may break it.